# Ubuntu locks laptop at 3% battery

Tags: power-management, battery

Alright, So I let my laptop's battery drain to 2% battery before pluging it into the charger to recharge but ubuntu acts funny around 3% and only 3%. When it gets that low, it locks my laptop to unlock it again, and I have checked my Dconf-Editior at `org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power` and the following settings are set: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Recent releases of Ubuntu have hibernation disabled by default, so it doesn't go into hibernation the way you have it set to.  Change `critical-battery-action` to suspend or shutdown instead.

Also you don't want to run the battery down below 20% or so if you can help it as it will shorten the life of the battery ( except maybe once every 6 months so the battery capacity can be recalibrated ).

Comment: So, I'm killing the battery life by letting it drain to about 2% ?

Comment: @KyleMorehead, yes.  Batteries do not like being fully discharged.  A battery might get 3000 charge cycles if you recharge it at 50% every time, 1000 going to 20% every time, and maybe only 400 cycles if you go down to 5% or less each time.